# Convert log equation in java

Tags: java, math, logarithm

i have this equation and im having trouble converting it into java code. The main problem is the "^" operator. I'm not sure how to take a power of an expression.

Here is the equation:

[image]

Very quick clarification, its log(5) +1 in the beginning.

Hope someone can help.

Here is the first part of the equation i wrote:

```
        double equationPart1 =  (((-0.5*Math.log(5)) +1)/2);
        double equationPart2 = 0;//the last part
        double equationPart3 = ((level * Math.log(5)) - (0.5 * Math.log(5)) + equationPart2);
```

Comment: Ever thought of using `pow` from the math library?

Comment: oh can pow take in expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thumb rule: try to make your equations as readable as possible.

```
double A = -0.5 * Math.log10(5) + 1;
double B = level * Math.log10(5);
double C = 0.5 * Math.log10(5);
double D = 0.5 * Math.log10(5) - 1;
double E = Math.pow(D/2, 2);

double club = (A/2) + (B - C  + E);    // OR double club = (A/2) - (B - C  + E);
double result = Math.pow(10.0, club);
```

Comment: quick question, whats the difference between, Math.log and Math.log10?

Comment: quick answer - what are javadocs for?

Comment: Lol... `Math.log`: Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value. Whereas  later one is for base 10

Comment: well i upvoted it to 0. and yeah sounds good. will accept it

Comment: Why stop at equations?  All code should be written to be as readable as possible.  Good answer, though.